# Forking an app in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have the following problem: I need to run an android app in an emulator, get to a certain state in it, after which I want to fork the process into two and do different actions in the app starting from that state.

Example: I want to open Yelp in the emulator, after which I want to search for "Coffee", then fork the process into 10, and in each child process open different coffee place.

The particular problem is how to perform the fork.

I've been trying to explore solutions to this problem, and found no easy way to do it. The options I explored the possibility of so far are:

1. Actually fork the app process within the emulator. This appears to be completely impossible.
2. Somehow fork the emulator process with an app running in it. There's no easy way to fork an external process, so I guess I would have to change the emulator code to fork from within when certain external event happens.
3. Put the emulator in some sort of a VM, which supports hot cloning. I haven't found any VM that actually supports it without serious downtime.

Ideally I want a solution that doesn't double the memory (similar to how `fork` in Linux works), and that is not associated with a significant downtime, though any solution that doesn't have the above two properties would also be acceptable.

Comment: For some reason your question brings to mind this post from @Commonsware about Parallel Spaces https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/17/droidception.html - just making you aware of it if you aren't already.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, while this doesn't immediately address my problem, it is actually very relevant to some other problems I'm facing, thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that's quite the task. Intuitively, I would expect option 2 to be the most promising.
Alternatively, have you considered writing an UIAutomator script and having it run in parallel or consecutively across a few devices? The bonus criteria would definitely not be met, but after sufficient runtime you might get what you're looking for.

1. Bring emulator into the state at which you want to fork
2. Save snapshot
3. Spawn emulator, specifying snapshot
4. Run UIAutomator script
5. Record findings
6. GOTO 3

Comment: How can I take a snapshot in (2)? I can't find anything about snapshots on the UIAutomator page, and the emulator doesn't seem to have this option too.

Comment: There are commandline options for that. Please see $ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -help

Comment: while this doesn't address the exact problem I described in the question, it does solve my particular scenario. Thanks!